# Dynamic AND OR operator in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, logical-operators

I have the following data in a table:

```
 condId condGrpId condVal Flag
 1      1         true     1
 2      1         false    1
 3      1         true     0
 1      2         true     1
 4      2         false    1
 1      3         true     1
 3      3         true     1
```

The above table represents condition  groups which are collection of conditions. The "condVal" column represents whether a condition is true or false.The "Flag" column represents the operator for the conditions. if the flag value is 1, then the corresponding condition will be used as an "AND" condition within the condition group, otherwise "OR".From the above table, I want to fetch the "condGrpId"s for which all conditions are true depending on the "Flag"s.e.g CondGrpId "1" has 3 conditions.For both the ist and 2nd row the Flag value is "1". This means the "condVal"s for 1st and 2nd row will be connected by AND operator.The Flag value for 3rd row in the condition group is "0".This means it will be connected with a "OR" operator.

I want to fetch the "condGrpId"s for true conditions on applying operators.
How to write a generic query to get CondGrpIds for this?

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the boolean expressions withing each CondGrp? I.e. for 1 that would be ( true & false ) or true => true, for 2: ( true & true ) => true and 3: ( false and true ) and true => false

Comment: Yes.I want to evaluate boolean expressions in each CondGroup.For CondGroup 1 that would be (true and false) or false. For 2 true and false.For 3 true and true.

Comment: @user3458122 why you do not accept the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with add_bool as
(
    select condId, condGrpId, condVal, Flag
    , case condVal when 'true' then 1 else 0 end [condBool]
    , row_number() over(partition by condGrpId order by condId) [row_id]
    from #your_table
)
, base as
(
    select [row_id], condId, condGrpId, condVal, Flag, [condBool], 1 [counter]
    from add_bool
    where condId = 1
    union all
    select t.[row_id], t.condId, t.condGrpId, t.condVal, t.Flag
    , case t.flag 
       when 1 then t.[condBool] & b.[condBool] 
       else t.[condBool] | b.[condBool] 
    end
    , [counter] + 1
    from add_bool t
    join base b on b.condGrpId = t.condGrpId
    and b.[row_id] + 1 = t.[row_id]
    where t.condId > 1
)
, ranked as
(
    select *
    , row_number() over(partition by condGrpId order by [counter] desc) [is_max_counter]
    from base 
)
select condGrpId, condVal
from ranked
where [is_max_counter] = 1
```

Result

```
condGrpId   condVal
-------------------
1           true
2           false
3           true
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31bc5e/4)

Comment: An alternative to the case expressions are: `case t.flag when 1 then t.[condBool] * b.[condBool] else (t.[condBool] + b.[condBool]) - (t.[condBool] * b.[condBool]) end`. Just a thought

Comment: maybe it will be useful - I changed CASE statement one more time, now with logical operators:  `case t.flag 
       when 1 then t.[condBool] & b.[condBool] 
       else t.[condBool] | b.[condBool] 
    end`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the bitwise operators. That is clearly better. One might even eliminate the outer case with `((t.flag = 1) & t.[condBool] & b.[condBool]) | ((t.flag = 0) & (t.[condBool] | b.[condBool]))` .

Comment: cool! by I better leave this `CASE` statement as is because it looks much more clear and familiar than long bitwise operation with parentheses. but anyway - thanx!

Comment: I agree, it was just a side-note

Answer (score 0):

check this...

```
 select condGrpId,flag ,condVal

 from tbl 

where condVal='true' group by condGrpId ,flag,condVal
```

check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/756f6/1